# Sequence-before relation in comma-separated variable definitions

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

Let's begin with the following example code:

`int a = 0, b = a++, c = a;`

Is `a++` sequenced before `a` (within `c = a`)? `a++` and `a` seem to qualify as full expressions, and according to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) (Rule 1), the answer should be positive. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Did you try it and see what happens? Or are you concerned that a different compiler might give different results?

Comment: @Chris Try it and see what happens is not a good way to determine if you have UB or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. As [Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29761114/sequence-before-relation-in-comma-separated-variable-definitions#comment47654594_29761138) points out, this is not a comma operator, but rather an *init-declarator-list*. From [dcl.decl] we have:

> Each *init-declarator* in a declaration is analyzed separately as if it was in a declaration by itself.

With a footnote which clarifies:

> A declaration with several declarators is usually equivalent to the corresponding sequence of declarations each with a single
>   declarator. That is
>
> ```
> T D1, D2, ... Dn;
> ```
>
> is usually equivalent to
>
> ```
> T D1; T D2; ... T Dn;
> ```
>
> where `T` is a *decl-specifier-seq* and each `Di` is an *init-declarator*.

There are two exceptions, one for a name hiding a type and one for `auto`, neither of which apply. So ultimately, the code you have is exactly equivalent to:

```
int a = 0;
int b = a++;
int c = a;
```

Which you should prefer to write in the first place since it doesn't take searching through the standard to ensure that you're doing something valid!

Comment: The comma separating declarators in a declaration is not a comma operator.

Comment: @Brian Hm. Does a declarator count as a full-expression?

Comment: Yes, see [dcl.decl]/3: "Each *init-declarator* in a declaration is analyzed separately as if it was in a declaration by itself." The footnote clarifies that such declarations are considered in the proper sequence. This answers the OP in the affirmative. I was going to write an answer, but I guess you can just edit yours.

Comment: @Brian If by edit you mean completely rewrite? Sure :)